# jquery contains: get 1st instance of

Tags: jquery

I have a table with the following rows:

- apple
- basket
- peach
- ball
- brine
- apron
- car
- cook
- pear
- plum
- choke

I have create a timer solution where the user can start typing a partial word and I would like to be able to highlight that row of data.

I was able get some information by doing the following:

```
console.log($('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:contains("' + filterString + '")'));
```

However, when I type the letter "c" for example I get the following results:

- peach
- car
- choke
- cook

Really what I would want is to change the css on the very first instance of the word that starts with 'c'.

I looked into the selectors (i.e. ~=) but that didn't seem to work.  What is the best way to accomplish a filter matching from the 1st letter in the list?

**UPDATE:**

All the suggestions are really close, but my example was a little off.  I updated the list above to be more accurate.  In the above list all the solutions below still bring back "peach" if my filter is the letter "c".

Sorry for the mistake.

**Update #2**

ShankarSangoli solution is on the right path but I'm still having issues for example if I type in the characters 'ce' I'm getting a match on:

**Absence** rather than on **certificate**

What is the best way to make sure I search on the beginning of the word rather than the entire word?

Comment: Are you looking for the first element matched, or elements whose first letter match your filter string, or the first of such elements?

Comment: I am looking for the first of the elements whose first letter match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   //To select only the rows that start with filterstring
   var filteredList =  $('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:contains("' + filterString + '")').filter(function(i){

       return $(this).text().indexOf(filterString) == 0;

    })

  //To set the css for first element in the filteredList
  filteredList.eq(0).css({ fontWeight: "bold" });
```

Comment: @Jeff - Take a look at my edited answer, hope that helps you.

Comment: That is very good.  I know I didn't mention this in my question but how would it change if I needed a combination of characters?  What if typed in 'ch'.  In my list I would want to highlight 'choke'.  Using your example how would you do that?

Comment: `ch` will highlight `choke` in the above code because I am using indexOf, just try it.

Comment: I did...  and you are right in my example it does...  but in the real world app that I'm working off of the list is much greater with many words that are simliar (i.e. apply, applicant, appraisal, approval etc).    I'm still getting instances where the letter combination is still matching if it is at the end of the word (for example : ce - Absence... - where I'm looking for certificate).

Comment: It will not match the string if its at the end. Because `indexOf()` returns the index from where it matches the string and I am checked for` index === 0`. Technically it should work as expected.

Comment: in your answer you put '==' should it be '==='    ?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2242/discussion-between-jeff-v-and-shankarsangoli)

Answer (score 3):

To match text that starts with a substring you would need to implement a new selector:

```
$.expr[':'].startsWith = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
  return ($(obj).text().indexOf(meta[3]) == 0);
};
```

You also need to append a [first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

```
$('#' + ListBoxVal + ' tr:startsWith("' + filterString + '"):first');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the regex selector by Padosley: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/ or the match selector plugin.

begin your regex with a ^ which means the it must begin with that.

Answer (score 1):

`$(...anything...).eq(0)` will give you the first result.